# React/Three.js project hosted on Vercel has bad performances but works fine locally

Tags: reactjs, performance, three.js, 3d, vercel

I have a simple React project in which I use Three.js to have a 3D scene. I had the expected result locally so I decided to host it on Vercel but the performances are not the same. Locally I easily reach 40-60 fps but the hosted version barely reaches 15 fps (my computer has an integrated GPU).
I really don't understand why, as both versions are the same. The app is not linked to a backend or anything, and I made sure no requests were made to the server after the app loaded.

Does it have something to do with Vercel specifically? I've not been able to find any documentation about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't really know where to search.

Comment: I don't think it's a Vercel issue. Maybe it's somehow initializing multiple canvases or running extra work in the background, but it's impossible to help you without [a working example of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the JS code from the 3D model? or directly create the 3d scene with coding ? . Check whethere you have a large size .bin file in repo.
I hosted a React Three.js project on Vercel
[Demo- zoom out using the mouse to see whole scene](https://react-3dmodel-visualize.vercel.app/)

You can have an idea of code [here](https://github.com/ksandaru/react-3dmodel-visualize)

**ModelSmallNumbered.js(child) has the 3d model**

**RailwayNumbered.js(parent) has the scene for that 3d model.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).